# Memory (physical & virtual pages) runs out for unknown reason

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, memory, windows-event-log

Recently our server becomes hanging quite often. I suspect a memory leak, yet still cannot find any suspect. The Event Log records the situation like this:

```
- <SystemInfo>
  <SystemCommitLimit>49195651072</SystemCommitLimit> 
  <SystemCommitCharge>49195651072</SystemCommitCharge> 
  <ProcessCommitCharge>3172712448</ProcessCommitCharge> 
  <PagedPoolUsage>432541696</PagedPoolUsage> 
  <PhysicalMemorySize>16983396352</PhysicalMemorySize> 
  <PhysicalMemoryUsage>16197967872</PhysicalMemoryUsage> 
  <NonPagedPoolUsage>183476224</NonPagedPoolUsage> 
  <Processes>139</Processes> 
  </SystemInfo>
- <ProcessInfo>
```

As you see, the SystemCommitCharge reaches SystemCommitLimit (~45GB), but the ProcessCommitCharge is merely 3GB.

I even check the 3 processes which use the most memory at that time, but together they only use about 1GB. There are about 100 processes more, but each of them uses 50MB at most.

> Windows successfully diagnosed a low virtual memory condition. The
>   following programs consumed the most virtual memory: sqlservr.exe
>   (4480) consumed 565637120 bytes, mysqld.exe (4500) consumed 362201088
>   bytes, and java.exe (1628) consumed 314191872 bytes.

Everything seems to indicate that there are something other than my processes which hog the resource.

One more thing I notice is that currently (after system restart) our Committed memory and Cache increase a lot compared to normal memory use. However, when double-check with Rammap, I see most of the memory is Stand By, which means it should not affect system performance. Also, non-paged memory is only 133MB now, so drivers' fault should not be the issue. I'm clueless.

Checking our server closely for 3 days, I can see that used memory increase little by little, from:

(30/08)

> In Use = 3.4 GB  Committed = 5.3 GB Cached = 2.2 GB Paged Pool = 225
>   MB Non-paged Pool = 76.2 MB
>   to

(01/09)

> In Use = 3.9 GB Committed = 23.9 GB Cached = 11.9 GB Paged Pool = 335
>   MB Non-paged Pool = 133 MB

Is there a way to detect this "mysterious factor" at play?

Answer (score 1):

You could check for memory leaks using Poolmon...

It's part of the Windows Driver Kit (WDK).

Some helpful links from Microsoft:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff545405(v=VS.85).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff550458.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff550442(VS.85).aspx

Comment: thanks, I'm trying poolmon. Seeing some suspects here and there, but I cannot find the meaning of tag names: CM31, MMst, NtfF, Ntff, MmRe... still in research for this.

Comment: In such cases I usually go to Google and add the word "driver".  Example:  Googling "CM31 driver" nets suggestions on how to find the driver yourself.  It is going to be a driver on your system, which may not be on all other systems.  Many sites suggest a findstr command run in C:\Windows\Drivers to help you identify the culprit.